# Is there any built-in package for a command-line interpreter in golang?

Tags: go

I would like to create command-line tool like `git`, `go` or `aws` in which we will pass some sub-commands to the main command and the last sub-command could also have some flags. Some examples are:

```
git add <file>
go build <file>
aws s3 cp --recursive <src> <dest>
```

Here are some examples of my hypothetical tool:

```
mytool cmd1
mytool cmd2 -f <path>
mytool cmd3 -f1 -f2 value --flag3 <path>
```

I know we can use the `fmt` package for defining and parsing flags, but I don't know if this package gives me the feature I described above or not. I was wondering if there is any built-in package for doing so?

Comment: The built-in `flag` package provides the feature. This package is used by the `go build <file>` command mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

just do a simple search on google and you can find anything

- http://blog.ralch.com/tutorial/golang-subcommands/
- https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags

Comment: Before trying third-party packages, I'd like to first see if there is an easy way to do this with Go build-in libs.